# •Informatica powercentre target xsd assistance

Tags: xml, xsd, target, repeat, informatica-powercenter

I have an xml target in powercentre designer, I have a repeatable address value in my schema, I need to map 5 postal address values eg addr 1, addr2, addr3, etc, (each have a different type value that also needs mapping to the target).

When I try and map across from my expression transformation connecting the lines it will only allow one connection to the type and value in the target.

Any ideas on a quick way so I can map  address 1-5 to this in the target below?

```
      <xsd:element name="Address">
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="part" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                      <xsd:sequence>
                      </xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string">
                      </xsd:attribute>
                      <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:string">
                      </xsd:attribute>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                  </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You have to normalize your source row so that each address comes in a separate row. Then you can map the one address column to the target. Of course, you have to populate an unique key for each address.

Comment: Any further info? I have data ready to be pulled from an expression, but have eg address 1, address2, 3 in it etc. target only shows one part,type,value to drag too. Many thanks

Comment: Use a normalizer to break the addresses in seperate rows. And use a sequence generator/or a count variable for the key. Then you should be able to connect it to the target. If you can provide a screen shot of your expression and target, probably we will be able to help you further.